# Custom Method in WCF Odata Entity

Tags: .net, wcf, api, rest, odata

I would like to add a custom method to one of Entity in my WCF OData project. Currently i have my service up and running.

For all tickets : http://local.host/api/TicketService.svc/Ticket
For one ticket  : http://local.host/api/TicketService.svc/Ticket(guid'9b265742-b1a0-41bd-8623-041a6a154b92')

These url's are working well. Now i need to implement print functionality to my service. (It will trigger some process related with Ticket)

I want to create a function for printing at Entity level and i will trigger with POST request. For example like this url

http://local.host/api/TicketService.svc/Ticket(guid'9b265742-b1a0-41bd-8623-041a6a154b92')/Print

Is that possible to create custom method in DataService class ?

Answer (score 0):

For WCF Data Services 5.0 and above, you can implement actions to accomplish this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/10/actions-in-wcf-data-services-part-1-service-author-code.aspx

http://efactionprovider.codeplex.com/

Comment: Unfortunately i am not using Entity Framework and we have less chance to update WCF version. Do you have another solution for previous version of WCF Data services ?